# In MATLAB, for a 2D array how do I get an index that will iterate the other dimension first

Tags: arrays, matlab, row-major-order, column-major-order

I've got an algorithm that fills a 2x3 subplot array using a single index `i=1:6`.

According to the documentation,

> `subplot(m,n,p)` divides the current figure into an m-by-n grid and
>   creates an axes for a subplot in the position specified by p. MATLAB®
>   numbers its subplots by row, such that the first subplot is the first
>   column of the first row, the second subplot is the second column of
>   the first row, and so on.

So when iterating over a 2x3 subplot array using `i=1:6`, would result in the following row-major order:

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
+---+---+---+
```

If I want fill the subplots in column-major order, I would have to convert my index 1 2 3 4 5 6 to 1 4 2 5 3 6.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can create an array of positions e.g Pos=[1 4 2 5 3 6] and iterate over that when you subplot e.g subplot(2,3,Pos(i)) and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a 2D array of indices that is `3 x 2`, transpose it to be `2 x 3` and then column-major has become row-major relative to the initial matrix.

```
indices = reshape(1:6, [], 2).';
```

Then you can create your subplots by looping through these indices

```
for k = 1:numel(indices)
    subplot(2, 3, indices(k))
end
```

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Why would that be faster?